# Getting data using webscraping (Obtaining links from search engine with redirect)

Tags: import, web-access, html, webservices

In the past I have used the function [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) in relation with `"Hyperlink"` to collect hyperlinks and data from the internet.

For example:

```
Import["https://www.google.nl/search?q=Wolfram", "Hyperlinks"]
```

gives a list with all hyperlinks. In the next step I can use these hyperlinks to scrape the web pages. This works fine.

When I want to use the search engine *DuckDuckGo*, like:

```
Import["https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Wolfram%22&t=h_&ia=web", "Hyperlinks"]
```

the output is:

> { "https://duckduckgo.com//?t=h_",
>   "https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22Wolfram%22" }

When I go to the webpage of *DuckDuckGo* and type a question, then I get a full list of search results. My question is:

**How can I collect this data using *Wolfram Language*?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's step back and do something simpler:

```
Import["https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Wolfram%22&t=h_&ia=web"]
(* "Ignore this box please.

DuckDuckGo

You are being redirected to the non-JavaScript site.
Click here if it doesn't happen automatically." *)
```

Oh, you are been redirected! To where?

```
Import[
 "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Wolfram%22&t=h_&ia=web",
 "Hyperlinks"
 ]
(* {"https://duckduckgo.com//?t=h_", "https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22Wolfram%22"} *)
```

Aha!, here `"https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22Wolfram%22"`

Then we better use `"https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q="` directly

```
getLinks[query_String] := Union@Import[
   StringTemplate["https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22``%22\""]@
    URLEncode[query]
   , "Hyperlinks"
   ]


getLinks["Mathematica"]
```

Comment: Hi, this is a nice answer. Below the duckduckgo page you can go to the next page. Do you have a suggestion how to do that with a Mathematica Script?

Comment: @MichielvanMens No, I don't. The *next* button is a `"POST"` form, it gets complicated. In any case, you are moving the goalpost to a place that is is no longer a Mathematica question. Let's stay on-topic.

Comment: @MichielvanMens in Mathematica 11.3 look at [`"WebDriver-Chrome"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html) which allows `"ClickElement"`.

Comment: @MichielvanMens I have posted a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178964/10397) and [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178965/10397) that may help you