# Programmatic browser interaction: How to click on web-page and get new URL and list of links

Tags: web-access, webservices, webdriver

In *Mathematica* it's easy to [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) data from the web and perform all sort of [Web Operations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WebOperations.html). But the later doesn't allow to simulate a more interactive browser operations, such as a *"Click"* action into a button or link. This may be relevant, for instance in in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/177106/10397), where a follow-up [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177106/getting-data-using-webscraping-obtaining-links-from-search-engine-with-redirect/177107#comment464862_177107) asked for the *"next page"*.

How can we open a web-page, click a particular button or link and extract relevant information such as the URL, page source and list of links of the new web-page?

Answer (score 8):

Since *Mathematica 11.3* there is an experimental implementation for [WebDriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver), a proposed *W3C* standard that currently supports Chrome and Firefox web browsers. It allows actions such as `"OpenWebPage"`, `"CaptureWebPage"` (Image), `"JavascriptExecute"`, and mouse operations such as `"ClickElement"` and `"HoverElement"` among others.

There is no documented option to get the URL or the page source, but a simple inspection of the implementation reveals some internal function of interest, including

```
WebUnit`GetURL
WebUnit`PageLinks
WebUnit`GetPageHtml
```

and more.

The following code opens *Chrome* on *Google Maps*, captures an image and extract the modified URL, which is a modified URL that includes the detected location.

```
Module[
 {
  session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"],
  iws, chromedo, img, links
  },
 chromedo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
 Pause[1];
 iws = ExternalEvaluateWebDriver`Private`websession[];
 Pause[1]; (* Time to load chrome *)
 chromedo["OpenWebPage" -> "https://maps.google.com"];
 Pause[5]; (* Time to load the page *)
 img = chromedo["CaptureWebPage"];
 Echo@WebUnit`GetURL[iws];
 (*links=Union@WebUnit`PageLinks[iws];*)
 DeleteObject[session];
 img
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following opens *Firefox*, searches in *DuckDuckGo*, locates a link to a twitter account, shows it (scroll down), clicks on it and then closes.

```
Module[
 {
  session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Firefox"],
  query = 
   StringTemplate["https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%22``%22\""]@
    URLEncode["mathematica stackexchange"],
  located
  },
 ffoxdo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
 Pause[10];
 ffoxdo["OpenWebPage" -> query];
 Pause[1];
 located = 
  ffoxdo["LocateElements" -> <|"PartialLinkText" -> "@StackMma"|> ];
 ffoxdo["ShowElement" -> located];
 Pause[1];
 ffoxdo["ClickElement" -> First[located]];
 Pause[10];
 DeleteObject[session];
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting to see that WebUnit is how they're doing this. It was originally an [Arnoud Buzing](https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/webtools) project.