# Import data from a current web session?

Tags: import, data-acquisition, websession

Consider opening a web session such as (Mathematica 11.3)

```
session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"];
ffoxdo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
```

Then we can navigate to a webpage, e.g.

```
ffoxdo[ "OpenWebPage" -> "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/New+York+NY+10017:4:US"];
```

After that the respective browser is showing a website. Now I would like to import the current content of that web browser as a data table into Mathematica. If I try

```
Import[session, "Data"]
```

the operation fails, which is not too surprising. I assume there is a special syntax for that? How should I do this properly?

PS:

The actual website I would like to get data from takes a second to load the relevant data into view, which is why I am trying to access it through a session instead of using `Import[httplink]` (the data is missing if I do that).

EDIT:

While [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178964/programmatic-browser-interaction-how-to-click-on-web-page-and-get-new-url-and-l) mentions a function that might lead to a solution "WebUnit`GetPageHtml", it does not solve the issue raised here per se. Making use of two more lines, we can load the html as

```
session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"];
ffoxdo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
iws = ExternalEvaluateWebDriver`Private`websession[];
ffoxdo[ "OpenWebPage" -> "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/New+York+NY+10017:4:US"];
html=WebUnit`GetPageHtml[iws];
DeleteObject[session];
```

However, the goal is to extract data from the `html` code, similarly to what the output of

`Import["https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/New+York+NY+10017:4:US","Data"]`

would give. Trying `Import[html,"Data"]` leads to an error. How should I be doing this properly?

Comment: Look at `WebUnit\`GetPageHtml` in [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178964/10397) If that link does not answer your question, do let us know, otherwise probably you may not get an answer.

Comment: @rhermans The link you point to seems to suggest a useful function, but there are still some issues left. Please, see my edit above.

Comment: Can you say what is the actual website and data you want?

Comment: @rhermans I am actually looking at https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/SPY/options?moneyness=allRows , the data being in the table that is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work on Mathematica 11.3, and not in 12 as `websession[]` seems to have changed.

```
Module[
 {
  session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"],
  iws, chromedo, img, links
 }, 
 chromedo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
 Pause[1];
 iws = ExternalEvaluateWebDriver`Private`websession[];
 Pause[1];(*Time to load chrome*)
 chromedo[
  "OpenWebPage" -> 
  "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/SPY/options?moneyness=allRows"
   ];
 Pause[15];(*Time to load the page*)
 Echo@WebUnit`GetURL[iws];
 html = WebUnit`GetPageHtml[iws];
 DeleteObject[session];
 ]
TableForm[ImportString[html, {"HTML", "Data"}][[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In 11.3 you can do:

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "JavascriptExecute" -> 
  "return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"]
```

In 12.0 and up, the syntax has change a little bit:

```
session = StartWebSession[]; 

WebExecute[session, "OpenWebPage" -> 
  "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/New+York+NY+10017:4:US"]

html = WebExecute[ session, "JavascriptExecute" -> 
  "return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"]
```

Note that the Wolfram Language comes with a [WeatherData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html) function built-in, so
you don't need to scrape data from a web page.

Also the [National Weather Service](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) has an public API, which might give you a more structured way to get this sort of data.

You import the `html` above with this:

```
ImportString[ html, "XMLObject" ]
```

This gives you a Wolfram Language expression that you can traverse with `Part`, `Take` and use with functions like `Cases`.

If your actual interest is stocks, then you should probably be aware of the [FinancialData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly stupid workaround to solve the above problem.

As suggested by [rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans), we can first obtain the html text of the webpage after it has finished loading:

```
session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"];
ffoxdo[cmd_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, cmd];
iws = ExternalEvaluateWebDriver`Private`websession[];
ffoxdo[ "OpenWebPage" -> "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/New+York+NY+10017:4:US"];
Pause[3];
html=WebUnit`GetPageHtml[iws];
DeleteObject[session];
```

Then, since `Import` cannot be used directly on a string of html text, we save it to disk and load from there:

```
Export["my.txt", html];
RenameFile["my.txt", "my.html"];
data = Import["my.html", "Data"];
DeleteFile["my.html"];
```

Now `data` indeed contains the output I was hoping for. But the workaround of writing to disk first is kind of unsatisfactory.

Comment: *"since Import cannot be used directly on a string of html text"*.. may be  `ImportString`?

Comment: @rhermans trying `ImportString[html,"Data"]`, unfortunately the output is completely different and still contains a lot of HTML code.

Comment: @Kagaratsch if the output is completely different that's a bug. You should report it with code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You need `ImportString[html, {"HTML", "Data"}]`